# Suitable performance metric for an unbalanced multi-class classification problem?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation, metric

I have an unbalanced multi-class classification problem with the following class distributions:

```
Class 0: 17.1% 
Class 1: 63.2% 
Class 2: 19.7%
```

I am using scikit-learn's [Support Vector Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) with `'balanced'` class weights to classify samples into one of the three classes. However, I don't know what would be the most suitable performance metric to evaluate the result? So far I have been using [F1-micro](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score) score, but not sure if this is the best option for multi-class imbalance problems?

Answer (score 2):

There are many useful metrics which were introduced for evaluating the performance of classification methods for imbalanced data-sets. Some of them are **[Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)**, **[CEN](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.708.1668&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**, **[MCEN](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-94120-2_8)**, **[MCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)**, **[DP](https://eva.fing.edu.uy/pluginfile.php/69453/mod_resource/content/1/7633-10048-1-PB.pdf)**, etc.

Disclaimer:

If you use python, **[PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm)** module can help you to find and calculate these metrics.

Here is a simple code to get the recommended parameters from this module:

```
>>> from pycm import *

>>> cm = ConfusionMatrix(matrix={"Class1": {"Class1": 1, "Class2":2}, "Class2": {"Class1": 0, "Class2": 5}})  

>>> print(cm.recommended_list)
["Kappa", "SOA1(Landis & Koch)", "SOA2(Fleiss)", "SOA3(Altman)", "SOA4(Cicchetti)", "CEN", "MCEN", "MCC", "J", "Overall J", "Overall MCC", "Overall CEN", "Overall MCEN", "AUC", "AUCI", "G", "DP", "DPI", "GI"]

>>> score = cm.Kappa
```